# Cisco remote VPN with Windows native client

Tags: windows-10, vpn

Today we are using Shrewsoft VPN client L2TP/IPsec IKEv1 to access the office,  remote access VPN with a shared key.
I am trying to tweak our current Cisco ASA 5505 configuration through asdm so I can use Windows 10 Native VPN instead of Shrewsoft client.

My VPN knowledge is pretty limited, but I have figured out that I get a mismatch error on phase 1 (from the Asa 5505 Syslog window when trying to connect).
It seems like the router is using DH group 2, and Windows is using DH group 5.

Where do I find what isakmp policy the Windows client is using? How I can match those on the router?
Is it possible to change this policy? I can only find settings for some authentication (CHAP/PAP) and data encryption...

Some advice on how to change these DH and encryption methods in asdm would also help.

Answer (score 0):

Can't help on the Windows side, but on the ASDM side, go to:

```
Configuration > Remote Access VPN > Network (Client) Access > Advanced > IPsec > IKE Policies
```

For more details see the [Cisco ASA Series VPN ASDM Configuration Guide](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa91/asdm71/vpn/asdm_71_vpn_config/vpn_asdm_ike.html)

Comment: Thx! I found the rest of the answers here: http://serverfault.com/questions/813256/windows-10-built-in-vpn